# Pre-Mendelian genetics

Tags: genetics, history

In the 18th century, [Joseph Gottlieb Kölreuter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Gottlieb_K%C3%B6lreuter) concluded from his plant experiments that in some hybrid generations the characteristics of grandmother generation, grandfather species and F1 generation were in ratio $1:2:1$. What does this imply? Does this mean that he observed a blending inheritance?

Comment: can you clarify the question with a quote or an example? it's not clear what the ratios refer to or how they match up with generations or what "hybrid" means in this context. (German is fine)

Comment: @MaximilianPress This is a paragraph from the Oxford's Gregor Mendel and the Roots of Genetics. Hybrids are, I think the F2 and the subsequent generation offsprings. The para tries to say that he got similar results what Mendel got but was unable to explain them. The grandmother and the grandfather I think refers to the Parental generation.

Comment: Can you provide the paragraph? Your question does not include a quote as far as I can tell. It might be easier to answer if we can actually see the text in question.